# error in installing xgboost for R in linux

Tags: r, linux, gcc, xgboost

I'm trying to install `xgboost` R package on my linux server using:

```
install.packages("xgboost", lib = "/usr/lib64/R/library")
```

It's giving me an error:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xgboost_0.6.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 596978 bytes (582 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 582 KB

* installing *source* package ‘xgboost’ ...
** package ‘xgboost’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
g++ -m64 -std=gnu++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I./include -I./dmlc-core/include -I./rabit/include -I. -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_  -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c xgboost_R.cc -o xgboost_R.o
In file included from ./dmlc-core/include/dmlc/logging.h:15,
                 from xgboost_R.cc:2:
./dmlc-core/include/dmlc/./base.h:71: note: #pragma message: Will need g++-4.6 or higher to compile allthe features in dmlc-core, compile without c++0x, some features may be disabled
xgboost_R.cc: In function ‘SEXPREC* XGBoosterSetAttr_R(SEXPREC*, SEXPREC*, SEXPREC*)’:
xgboost_R.cc:412: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [xgboost_R.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xgboost’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/xgboost’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xgboost’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpFDEVT8/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot create file '/usr/share/doc/R-3.4.2/html/packages.html', reason 'Permission denied'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot update HTML package index
```

It says g++-4.6 or higher needed.

I updated `gcc` on my server from 4.4.7 to 4.9.2. But, still it's giving me the same error.

Does anyone have any idea about this problem. How to solve this?

Comment: Seemingly, R does not know you have g++ 4.9.2 and calls the old one; hence the error.   Make sure that in a new shell `g++ --version` does in fact show 4.9.2.

Comment: I guess that's the problem. R doesn't know about new version. `gcc --version` is showing me 4.9.2 version.

Comment: But R invokes a `g++ -m64 ...` so it is not explicitly calling the old one.

Comment: I guess there was some problem with installation of `gcc`. Now, in newer session of putty it again shows me 4.4.7 version.

Comment: No, I'm not running R with sudo.

Comment: Go to `/usr/local/bin` and create a softlink (ie `ln -s from to`) from the new `gcc` and `g++`.  That may do the trick.   This really is your local issue; your default compiler is too old.

Comment: Can you please give me the exact commands? After switching to new `gcc` using `sudo source /opt/rh/devtoolset-3/enable` it shows me version of 4.9.2. But, `xgboost` is still not getting installed. Also, in  `/usr/bin` it just shows me one `gcc` and `g++`.

Comment: I said `/usr/local/bin` not `/usr/bin`.  And look at other tutorials for `ln -s`.

Comment: Created soft links for `gcc` and `g++` in `/usr/local/bin` using: `ln -s devtoolset-3-gcc.x86_64 gcc_4.9.2_link`. Still it's giving me the same error.

Comment: You need the full path: `cd /usr/local/bin;  sudo ln -s /opt/new/gcc/devtoolset-3-gcc.x86/bin/gcc gcc`.   Not some funky thing with `link` append.  You want R to call this.

Comment: Thanks so much Dirk. It worked. Please put it as an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way making a newer version of `gcc` and `g++` appear ready for R is to force it to appear early in the system `$PATH`.  Besides altering `$PATH`, one can use the fact that `/usr/local/bin/` normally comes before `/usr/bin` so that an added newer version will be preferred.

So assumming we installed a new `gcc` in `/opt/gcc/gcc-4.9.2/` we could do

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /opt/gcc/gcc-4.9.3/bin/gcc .
sudo ln -s /opt/gcc/gcc-4.9.3/bin/g++ .
```

which may sufficient. `ld`, `as`, `ar`, ... could be added but are not always needed.  Adjust the path as needed, and make sure you link the actual executable (ie `gcc`) as such into `/usr/local/bin`.

Check with `gcc --version`.

Answer (score 0):

I had xgboost installation issues. An older archived version (‘0.90.0.2’) can be however be installed, and it works!

```
packageurl <- "http://cran.r- 
project.org/src/contrib/Archive/xgboost/xgboost_0.90.0.2.tar.gz"

install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```